# PHP Calculated Value connected to the Parameter

Tags: php, random

i have a question. It's about a calculated data, that depends on a String - Parameter that i will give to the function.

For Example:

```
    function calculatedData($parameterString){
         //CALCULATION
         return RandValue;

    }
```

Theoretically i mean this for example. I will call the function calculatedData with the Parameter "Arthur", the function must create a calculated value that depends on the String "Arthur".
If i call the function twice with the Parameter "Arthur" it should return the same calculated value than the call-function before.

EXAMPLE:
1. Call Function -> calculatedData ("Arthur") -> Returns for Example 3482
2. Call Function -> calculatedData ("Lukas") -> Returns for Example 8542
3. Call Function -> calculatedData ("Arthur") -> Returns for Example 3482

I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: That's not random then. The purpose of randomness is that it's never the same.

Comment: It's hash, not random value

Comment: You want seed, but you call it random value. I propose you to read and learn a little. 

for seed you can use `hash('sha256')` or any other hash

Comment: And I think he wants that we write the hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example of a function which will hash a string to hexadecimal value (unique) and then convert to int :

```
function getHashCode($string){
    return hexdec(hash("adler32", $string));
}

echo getHashCode('my string'); // 297927582
echo getHashCode('other string'); // 528811226
echo getHashCode('string my'); // 314377118
```

You can change the algorithme (adler32) to another to avoid collisions. I used adler32 to limit the size of the int.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that random value should be string. If you want that the random value should be string of any specific length then you can simply send md5 of input string.

```
function randomData($parameterString){
  return md5($parameterString);        
}
```